# change part of text inside span jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to change part of text inside a span tag
I tried this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var toreplace= $(".poly-items__price span");
        toreplace = toreplace.replace("change","<p>new text</p>");
        $(".poly-items__price span").html(toreplace);
    });
</script>
```

here is a html:

```
<div class="poly-items__price">
    <span>do not change change</span>
</div>
```

here is an examples I used:
http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/a9cvx/4/,
http://jsfiddle.net/bwhfD/

but it doesn't working
can you tell me what I missed
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get text from `$(".poly-items__price span")` need call `.text()` (or `.html()` if you care about html tags inside span)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var toreplace= $(".poly-items__price span").text();
  toreplace = toreplace.replace("change","<p>new text</p>");
  $(".poly-items__price span").html(toreplace);
});
```

if you want replace all "change" use:

```
toreplace = toreplace.replace(/change/g,"<p>new text</p>");
```

here is some fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qsbdg4po/1

## Edit

If you have multiple `.poly-items__price` spans, use each loop:

```
$('.poly-items__price span').each(function() {
  var toreplace = $(this).html();
  toreplace = toreplace.replace("change","<p>new text</p>");
  $(this).html(toreplace);
});
```

Comment: You should not mix `html()` and `text()`. If you take `text()`, set `text()` (not working in this case). If you take `html()`, set `html()` (dangerous as it is in general case).

Comment: @Sojtin right, in my come it display all values from everyone span tag, but not change text

Comment: Y not you remove the html tag `<p></p>` when you are using `.text()` instead of `.html()`. Check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7r0gv1br/

Comment: @Sojtin Edited code is absolutly correct, thank's a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass a function to jQuery.html

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".poly-items__price span").html(function() {
              return $(this).html().replace("change","<p>new text</p>");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="poly-items__price">
  <span>do not change change</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

you can alse use `$(toreplace).find("span").html(str);` for replacing content of span

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var toreplace= $(".poly-items__price");
       var str = $(toreplace).find("span").text().replace("change","<p>new text</p>");
     $(toreplace).find("span").text(str);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="poly-items__price">
    <span>do not change</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var toreplace= $(".poly-items__price span").html();
    toreplace = toreplace.replace("change","<p>new text</p>");
    $(".poly-items__price span").html(toreplace);
     });
</script>
<div class="poly-items__price">
<span>do not change change</span>
</div>
```